# ORACLE : Use regular expression to filter data in field

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a table in Oracle :

```
id | name  | description

 1 | Roy   | 12
 2 | Boy   | 99
 3 | John  | NEW YORK
 4 | Brian | ALABAMA
```

I want to select rows 3 and 4 (containing letters only) with the following query, but I get no rows.

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE description LIKE '%[a-z0-9]%'
```

How to correct the query to get rows 3 and 4?

Comment: If you want to use regular expressions, you'd need to use `regexp_like` (or `regexp_instr` or `regexp_substr`).  Is your intention to show only rows where the `description` is composed exclusively of lower case letters and numbers?  Or rows where the `description` has at least 1 lower case letter or number?  Or something else?

Comment: @JustinCave : thank for your respon. I just want to show a line containing only letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE regexp_like( d, '^[a-zA-Z]+$')
```

[Try to check documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Multilingual-Regular-Expression-Syntax.html). Here's a brief 
overview:

```
   ^ - start of string
   $ - end of string
   [a-zA-Z] - character class containing latin letters only
   [0-9] - character class containing digits only
   \d - the same as [0-9]
```

For example:

`^[a-zA-Z]+$` matches string with letters ONLY

`^[a-zA-Z]` matches string started with letters and any tail

`[a-zA-Z]` matches string containg at least one letter anywhere

Similar rules for digits:

`^\d+$` matches string with digits ONLY (and so on ...)

`^\d{2,6}$` matches string if it contains digits ONLY and there are 2,3,4,5 or 6 digits in it.

Comment: <nitpick>For the query to also return the 'New York' row, you should include space in your character class.</nitpick>

Comment: @diziaq and All: If my column contains `Jakarta` or `jakarta` or `JAKARTA` or `jaKarta` or sometime just `comma (,)` then my regexp_like is ',[jJaAkKrRtT]'.  is true?

Comment: @diziaq, I want to store large text (news articles) in one of the columns and perform similar queries that filter using regex. Would Oracle be a good choice for a database? What would you recommend?

Comment: @Andy Definitely no: regexes are hard to use, hence such solution would open a door for bugs in your project. I'd recommend to look at text-focused solutions as they are more secure and tuned for performance than juggling raw strings and regexes. In case of Oracle it would be OracleText Other DBs for sure have something similar.

Comment: @diziaq thanks I did some research and I think I will go with Solr